# Google Adwords not Tracking Conversions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-ads-api

In my Rails app that uses the Devise gem, it redirects back to the root which has this code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40000000-1', 'foo.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/home/articles/user_sign_up']);
</script>
```

In Google Analytics I have `Destination` set to:

```
Equals to /home/articles/user_sign_up
```

However, it's not registering as a conversion.  Can someone please help me figure out what I did wrong?

The URL of the page that the code appears on is `/home/articles` so my intent was to try to overwrite what Google thought the URL was using:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/home/articles/user_sign_up']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are mixing up the new `analytics.js` syntax with the traditional `ga.js` one.
Try using

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/home/articles/user_sign_up');
```

See [the relevant documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding).